# Join attribute table - 2 different layers - 2 different classifications (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, attribute-joins, classification

I have 2 vector layers, one containing cells on a municipality level and one containing a more detailed classification on a district level. Some municipality contain multiple districts, whereas other municipality overlap 1:1 with the districts.
The borders of the municipality and districts are oughly equal, however, not 100% (see image).
red outline: municipality
black hatched outline: districts

[image]
Now, I would like to create a merged attribute table containing both the borders of the municipality and districts. It should look like the following:

[image]

I tried the attribute join based on the location, however, as the borders are not 100 % overlapping, I do not know which parameter to choose ("overlaps", "intersects", "contains" etc.). Then, I tried to merge both layers, but most of the attribute columns contained a NULL value. Also, using the field calculator did not help.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the GIS software in use.

Comment: If your district boundaries matched you could run an overlay (Intersect or Union) and then Aggregate (or use a pivot table).  Any area fields would need to be recalculated.  The Overlap Analysis tool might also provide the table you want.  The boundary mismatch means you would get slivers in any overlay or sliver like info in the Overlap Analysis.  You could use the Eliminate tool selecting on sliver area polygons at some point and get the rest manually.  There is also a Remove Self Overlapping polygons in the Process X plugin that might help.  That tool I haven't used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the district layer is of polygon geometry, I would recreate the boundary of the municipality based on the districts boundaries. That would solve one problem.

[image]

Just take the district boundaries layer and dissolve it based on the municipality name.

[image]